# Cypress tests passing locally but not passing in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, cypress

My Cypress tests are passing locally when running this command:

`npx cypress run --browser chrome --env api_endpoint="https://myApp.com",page="TestAppsForCdnIntegrations/myApp.html"`

However, when I run this in my Azure DevOps pipeline, I'm getting the below error:

```
2021-09-29T15:51:07.2749462Z *****************************************
2021-09-29T15:51:07.2762053Z  Run Cypress
2021-09-29T15:51:07.2771057Z *****************************************
2021-09-29T15:51:20.4370810Z   (Run Starting)
2021-09-29T15:51:20.4448402Z   │ Cypress:    6.9.1                                                                              
2021-09-29T15:51:20.4449343Z   │ Browser:    Chrome 94                                                                          
2021-09-29T15:51:20.4468328Z   Running:  examples\get_js_config.spec.js                                                  (1 of 7)
2021-09-29T15:52:20.4675196Z 
2021-09-29T15:52:20.4676105Z Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying...
2021-09-29T15:53:17.2314823Z EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Cypress\cy\production\browsers\chrome-stable\run-5596\CypressCache\Default\Cache\data_1'
2021-09-29T15:53:17.2316098Z Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Cypress\cy\production\browsers\chrome-stable\run-5596\CypressCache\Default\Cache\data_1'
```

I'm not sure why it's working locally, but not in the pipeline.

Can someone please advise what is causing this & how to resolve?

Comment: Assume you are using a hosted microsoft agent for this?

Comment: @Matt Yep, that's correct

Comment: Switching the browser from chrome to electron resolved the issue & the tests now pass in the pipeline. I'm wondering is it due to a recent Chrome update or maybe I need to update Cypress.