# Test result not displayed in azure and strange result using cypress run

Tags: node.js, azure, devops, cypress, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an issue though everything executed in the release pipeline successfully, I am not sure if that is how it should be. For example the test page displayed is not showing anything.

[image]

[image]

When I executed the PowerShell for the cypress run and I got this

[image]

[image]

Is the PowerShell page correct at all for the cypress run and how can I get the tests page to display the test results? I have read a lot and try many things and no result is displayed.

Comment: Have you tried these?  [Azure DevOps PublishTestResults not found junit cypress test result file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224454/azure-devops-publishtestresults-not-found-junit-cypress-test-result-file), [Cypress tests passing locally but not passing in Azure DevOps pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379813/cypress-tests-passing-locally-but-not-passing-in-azure-devops-pipeline) and [cypress - Troubleshooting](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Isolate-the-Problem)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Yes, I have looked at it and still the same thing. When I changed the directory to where cypress.json is located, it is giving error for - A missing file or dependency
2022-01-17T10:42:15.2873615Z - A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies